# HTML change mime type for download using chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, download, http-headers, mime-types

My extension creates 2 anchor links to download 2 files from a server. An mp4 video file and an m4a audio file.

The server has changed the Content-Type in the header of the m4a audio file from "audio/m4a" to "audio/mp4"

When you click on the download link for the m4a audio file, it saves it as ".mp4" because of the new Content-type "audio/mp4"

I've tried playing around with the "download" and "type" attributes of the links but chrome ignores them and only follows the Content-type.

How can I get the m4a file to download as .m4a instead of .mp4 because it causes confusion with the mp4 video file.

Can an ajax call initiating the download help specify the mime-type? or is this one of chrome's security measures that wont allow you to save the file as different than the specified content-type?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the explicit filename in the header:

```
$file="test.m4a";    
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename="'.$file.'"');
```

That works for me.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a php function? The server isn't mine, I'm just downloading from it. Would this work by intercepting the anchor click and downloading using ajax with setting the header?